# Jquery Multiple data on href

Tags: jquery

Consider this table where I need to pop up a new form when link is click

```
<td><?php echo $c['diameter'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $c['brand'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $c['model'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $c['load_index'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $c['qty'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $c['vendor'] ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $c['tire_id'] ?></td>
<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="changebtn" data-tireid="<?php echo $c['tire_id'] ?>" >Accept?</a></td>


 <script>
  $(".changebtn").click(function(){
  $("#readonlytire_id").val($(this).attr("data-tireid"));
   });
</script>
```

Now I have a hidden input type that Jquery will automatically populate a value

```
 <input id="readonlytire_id" type="hidden" name="tire_id">
```

But I need to modify this, instead I need to add 6 input under readonly_id
Something like

```
  <input id="readonlytire_id" type="hidden" name="tire_id">
  <input id="brand" type="hidden" name="brand">
  <input id="model" type="hidden" name="model">
  <input id="qty" type="hidden" name="qty">
```

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td id='diameter'><?php echo $c['diameter'] ?></td>
<td id='brand'><?php echo $c['brand'] ?></td>
<td id='model'><?php echo $c['model'] ?></td>
<td id='load_index'><?php echo $c['load_index'] ?></td>
<td id='qty'><?php echo $c['qty'] ?></td>
<td id='vendor'><?php echo $c['vendor'] ?></td>
<td id='tire_id'><?php echo $c['tire_id'] ?></td>

<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
class="changebtn" data-tireid="<?php echo $c['tire_id'] ?>" >Accept? 
</a></td>

<script>
    $(".changebtn").click(function(){
        $("#readonlytire_id").val($(this).attr("data-tireid"));
        // get the html value and feed the hidden fields with it
        $('#readonly_brand').val($('#brand').html());
        ... // same for all additonal fields
    });
</script>
```